# jQuery variable that takes text from text input box does not update

Tags: jquery, input

Here's my code:

```
            <input name="addCollectionInput" type="text" class="xlarge" value=""/> -->
            <input id="addCollectionInput" name="addCollectionInput" class="xlarge" type="text" />
            <input type="hidden" id="fromSideBar" name="fromSideBar" value="1" />
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<c:out value="${category.id}" />" /> -->
            </td>
            <td>
            <button id="addCategoryButton" class="addCategoryButton" type="button">+</button> <!-- class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  -->
            <script>   
            //Quand je clique sur le bouton "+"
            $(document).ready(function () 
            {
                $('#addCategoryButton').click(function () 
            {
            var
            val = $('#addCollectionInput').val(),
            $select = $('#subjectCategories');

            //Si la catégorie n'existe pas déjà...
            if ($select.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').length === 0 && val!="") 
            {
            //Ajouter la nouvelle catégorie dans la liste
            $('<option>', {
            value: val,
            text: val
            }).appendTo($select);

           //Vider le champ d'ajout de catégories
           $('#addCollectionInput').val("");
          }
          alert(val);
        });
    });
    </script>
</td>
```

Problem is, what ever I do, val is always null, although I write things in the text input called addCollectionInput. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want it constantly updated whenever someone types a letter?

Comment: No, I just want it to take into val the value that is in addCollectionInput when I click the button... but it always belives the value is null, even when it isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was pretty stupid and incomprehensible, but I only changed the text input's name and it worked fine!?